# Listview addrange from class using LINQ

Tags: c#

I wanna ask how I can translate this into LINQ version?

I'm storing an array of strings into the listview subitem.
someone told me that using LINQ is better and faster to add an array of strings.

here's my current code for adding strings from my class

```cs
        private async Task AddToListView(string url, MediaInfo info, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var lvi = new ListViewItem();

            lvi.Checked = true;
            lvi.Text = (info.Series);
            lvi.SubItems.Add("Episode " + info.Episode);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(info.Title);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(info.Runtime);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(info.Resolution);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(info.M3u8_link);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(info.Subtitle_url);
            lvi.SubItems.Add("waiting..."); //here where I store later the array strings
            lvi.SubItems.Add(url);

            LV.BeginUpdate();
            LV.Items.Add(lvi);
            LV.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            LV.AutoResizeColumn(1, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            LV.AutoResizeColumn(2, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            LV.AutoResizeColumn(3, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            LV.AutoResizeColumn(4, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
            LV.EndUpdate();

            lvi.SubItems[7].Text = await GetFragment(info, token); //downloading information / array of strings
        }
```

Comment: AddRange is faster than Add but Linq will (usually) not be faster. OTOH it will often (not alwqys) be quite convenient to write down..

Comment: Oh thank you for information. 
Do you have any suggestion to improve my current code?
sometimes it takes 1minute before adding the array strings

Comment: Linq or `Language Integrated Query`.  I don't see any queries. what is your data source?

Comment: I would collect the Lvi's in a List<ListViewItem> and addRange them when all are ready. It is the repeated layout that takes time. Contructing the Lvi's itself doesn't involve updating the screen, so adding the subitems one by one shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm about to post this idea :) could you check what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, the most compact way to write your code could be like this:

```
var lvi = new ListViewItem();

lvi.Checked = true;
lvi.Text = (info.Series);
IEnumerable<string> temp = new List<string>() { "Episode " + info.Episode, info.Title, info.Runtime, info.Resolution, info.M3u8_link, info.Subtitle_url, "waiting...", url };
lvi.SubItems.AddRange(temp.toArray());

LV.BeginUpdate();
LV.Items.Add(lvi);
for(var i=0; i<5;i++)
{
   LV.AutoResizeColumn(i, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
}

LV.EndUpdate();
lvi.SubItems[7].Text = await GetFragment(info, token);
```

As @AliReza said in comment, I don't think LINQ is useful in this case.

Comment: Wow I'm gonna try this now. 
This is what I'm looking for aside from LINQ

Comment: I got a little error here 
 lvi.SubItems.AddRange(temp); it says cannot convert from ...... string to ListviewSubItem[]

Comment: Happy to ear that! Let us know how it went!

Comment: Yes, good! I always forget it. Now I'm updateing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

version 2: suggested by Giovanni Esposito

```
string fragments = await GetFragment(info, token);

        var lvi = new ListViewItem
        {
            Checked = true,
            Text = (info.Series)
        };
        IEnumerable<string> temp = new List<string>() 
        { 
            "Episode " + info.Episode, 
            info.Title, 
            info.Runtime, 
            info.Resolution, 
            info.M3u8_link, 
            info.Subtitle_url, 
            fragments, url 
        };

        lvi.SubItems.AddRange(temp.ToArray());

        LV.BeginUpdate();
        LV.ListViewItemSorter = null;
        LV.Items.Add(lvi);
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            LV.AutoResizeColumn(i, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        }
        LV.EndUpdate();
```

version 1. My code.

```
 List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();

        string fragments = await GetFragment(info, token);

        items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] 
        { 
            info.Series, 
            "Episode " + info.Episode,  
            info.Title,
            info.Runtime,
            info.Resolution,
            info.M3u8_link,
            info.Subtitle_url,
            fragments,
            url
        }));
        ListViewItem[] array = items.ToArray();
        LV.BeginUpdate();
        LV.ListViewItemSorter = null;
        LV.Items.AddRange(array);
        LV.EndUpdate();
```